# Convert a variable to T in TypeScript generic methods?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I have the following `typescript` class, to get a model from `localStorage`

```
export class LocalStorageHelper {
    public static GetItemValue<T>(key: string): T {
        let value: string = localStorage.getItem(key);
        // if(typeof T == 'string') return value;
        // return (Convert JSON.parse(value) To T)
    }
}
```

How can I do something like comment lines in TypeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript get's compiled to JS, so there are no types at runtime, therefore you can't do anything like `typeof T` here. You need to pass somehow the type of the object you want to return. In your case I would have two separate methods, one for retrieving strings and another for parsing it into JSON.

```
export class LocalStorageHelper {
    public static GetItemValueString(key: string): string {
        let value: string = localStorage.getItem(key);
        return value;
    }
    public static GetItemValue<T>(key: string): T {
        let value: string = localStorage.getItem(key);
        return JSON.parse(value) as T;
    }
}
```

I would also note that even in strongly typed languages (like Java/Scala/C#) compiler wouldn't have any way of telling wether you want string or another object to be returned, as T is just a return type that you are using to determine what to return.